# Azure Active Directory B2C modify sign in to add custom attributes

Tags: azure-ad-b2c, custom-attributes

I am using AD B2C custom policy for sign in sign up process. I am getting a custom attribute named "Worksapce" from user while signing up. Is it possible to add this custom attribute as a drop down to sign in custom UI page so that user can select their workspace while signing in?

Answer (score 1):

As specified in the documentation [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/active-directory-b2c-configure-signup-self-asserted-custom), you should define the "workspace" claim type in your policy file (the TrustFrameworkBase.xml might be a good place to put in) e.g. using a dropdown. The Restriction node of your xml should be used to specify all possible values for your dropdown. 

Here an example:

```
<ClaimType Id="city">
  <DisplayName>city where you work</DisplayName>
  <DataType>string</DataType>
  <UserInputType>DropdownSingleSelect</UserInputType>
  <Restriction>
    <Enumeration Text="Bellevue" Value="bellevue" SelectByDefault="false" />
    <Enumeration Text="Redmond" Value="redmond" SelectByDefault="false" />
    <Enumeration Text="Kirkland" Value="kirkland" SelectByDefault="false" />
  </Restriction>
</ClaimType>
```

Then, You should add the claim to the sign up/sign in user journey. The official documentation explain how to accomplish those steps in a very detailed way [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/active-directory-b2c-configure-signup-self-asserted-custom#add-the-claim-to-the-sign-upsign-in-user-journey)